# Maximum characters Facebook comments?

Tags: character, facebook-comments, reduce

Is it possible to reduce the maximum characters so you get earlier the "read more" link?
I added comments this way to my website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

I dont want to let the comments stretch my webpage by lager comments...